# Are arguments for a point the same as benefits of a point?

Tags: definition

When there is a question asking for **arguments for** something, is that the same as asking for **the benefits of the point** I am taking about?

This is the actual question:

> "Answer with reference to arguments for and against ideas of capitalism based on shareholder value."

Comment: Hi xh, welcome to ELL! Can you edit to add more context (perhaps the exact question you were asked?). Context will help us give you better answers :)

Comment: "The arguments for and against" a thing are the reasons describing how the thing is good and the reasons describing how the thing are bad, usually posed as a balanced review of the thing as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

> When there is a question asking for arguments for something, is that
>   the same as asking for the benefits of the point I am taking about?

Yes they have the same meaning, but they're technically not exactly the same.

Your *argument for* something is the rationale behind your position. It also is the reason(s) that you desire that thing, which is where they overlap.

But, while your argument consists of pros and cons, they're more logical points for debate. If you're *arguing **for*** something, then someone's probably *arguing **against*** that thing.

When you ask for the *benefits of* any given thing, you're asking for the reasons it would be a good idea. But this doesn't have to be something you argue; it could be something for which your position is neutral. It's just a list of pros. They're not necessarily looking for a logical argument.

As you can see, the difference is extremely subtle, and for all intents and purposes, they're close to being the same.

With that said, your **argument** may include **both** pros **and** cons. It is not limited to positive aspects, which benefits are.

> "Answer with reference to arguments for and against ideas of
>   capitalism based on shareholder value."

The **arguments for** are the **benefits/pros**, whereas the **arguments against** are the **consequences/cons**.